# Match comma after 5 characters

Tags: regex

I have a requirement where I need to validate an input field.
It should be alphanumeric characters after 5 characters there should be **comma (,)**

**Example:**

K9,d3,dk,33,kd

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}[,]
```

but after **K9,** it gives that Regex pattern not matched

Comment: Yes, you won't get it matched because `[a-zA-Z0-9]` does not include `,`. Add [it and it will work](https://regex101.com/r/nQ5aF9/2). Also, no need to escape `,`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your regex says that the "," comma has to be after exactly 5 characters.
But you want a comma after every second char.

Try this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9,]{5}
```

And if it is always 2x chars followed by one comma try this:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]{2},)+
```

This means two chars followed by a comma which can appear one or more times.

And last but not least a shorten form:

```
(\w{2},)+
```

Good reference explaining regex in java: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: @BalusC Could you please explain you for the rest here why you changed my post this way? I understand your reason but for the rest they got no clou why you removed all jsfp code araound the regexes.

Comment: Question is about regex patterns, which are universal and language agnostic. JSF (or whatever language/framework/library utilizing regex) only adds irrelevant noise to the question/answer.